# Async Template loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to asynchronously load 25 html templates

Here's my code:

```
        var loopingLoadTemplate = function(index){
            var name = names[index];

            $.get('templates/' + name + '.html', function (data) {
                that.templates[name] = data;
                tplCount++;
                console.log(tplCount + " " + names.length);
                if (tplCount === names.length){
                    callback();
                }
            });
        };

        for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            loopingLoadTemplate(i);
        }
```

tplCount is a counter that I keep so I know when it's safe to fire the callback

the problem is that, there are 25 templates to load, and when I checked under network tab in Chrome console, I see all 25 templates getting loaded properly, but console.log tells me the tplCount stops at 21, which I have no idea why. Is it because the for loop is firing so fast that some callbacks of the $ functions did not fire?

How do I safely asynchronously load all these templates?

So I also tried an synchronously fallback using recursive calls, but it mysteriously stops after loading some templates and gives no warning sign

```
        var loadTemplate = function (index) {
            var name = names[index];

            console.log("loading " + names[index]);

            $.get('templates/' + name + '.html', function (data) {
                that.templates[name] = data;
                index++;
                if (index < names.length) {
                    loadTemplate(index);
                    console.log("trying another load");
                } else {
                    callback();
                    console.log("trying callback");
                }
            });
        };
        loadTemplate(0);
```

Comment: I bet that some of the templates are *not* loading successfully. I would try shortening the list of URLs and looking for ones that  don't work.

Comment: every template has a success status though..

Comment: Well, the fact is that things aren't working as you expect. Testing the code with a shorter list seems like a worthwhile experiment.

Comment: You might also try defining an error handler with `$.ajaxError()`, which will be called if jQuery thinks a request failed.

Comment: !! so strange, I just discovered that, in 4 of templates, it was empty..so my guess is that if a template is empty, the data in callback function becomes undefined and fails with no warning..fixed it by adding "<div></div>" to the empty templates

Comment: I guess that explains all my problems, now both async and sync functions work

Comment: Matthew, suggest you post your solution as an Answer and accept it. That way, it's more readily useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just figured out why its failing

so, indeed all the templates are loaded properly, but, if a html template has no content, the data in the callback function becomes undefined, instead of being empty as what I had expected

when the data is undefined, it fails the line:

```
that.templates[name] = data;
```

without any warnings or errors and the rest of the code in the callback are not excuted

since all the templates do get loaded, checking the network tab would give all status success result